# Kernel version for MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, linux-kernel

I have a server with kernel version 3.10. This seems to be a quite old kernel (though patches are backported). Is there any reason to force an update to kernel 5.x?

Comment: Unless you need a specific capability from the newer kernel version the answer is no. MySQL will run on systems with this kernel, for example CentOS 7.

Comment: In general, MySQL maintains broad compatibility with OSs.

Comment: You should make sure to use a supported version of your operating system, so that you receive all relevant security updates. Without regular security updates, your server could be compromised.